# How to Check Android Runtime Permissions/Get Android Current Activity from LibGdx Core Module?

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx

I'm learning/developing an Android/Kotlin/[Ktx](https://libktx.github.io/)  game that will need a [live speech recognizer](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/#livespeechrecognizer) from cmusphinx.

Now I'm struggling to check permissions at runtime. I already coded an [interface](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) from core to android.

The log gives me this error when executing the 'setupPermissions' function (code below):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

I guess it's because I am not getting the current activity. 
I can't find a tutorial explaining this.

How can I get the current activity to check the permissions on Android?

---

The code is as follows:

Core Module:

```
package com.folotera.controller

interface PermissionManager {
    fun checkPermissions()
}
```

Android Module:

```
class AndroidPermissionChecker : PermissionManager {

    private val RECORD_REQUEST_CODE = 101

    override fun checkPermissions(){
        setupPermissions()
    }

    private fun setupPermissions() {

        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity(),
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Permission to record denied")
            makeRequest()
        }
    }

    private fun makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity(),
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            RECORD_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

..

```
class AndroidLauncher : AndroidApplication() {
...
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 ... 
     val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
     initialize(aGame(AndroidPermissionChecker()), config)
  ...
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be instantiating an Activity or Context yourself. Android provides you with the Context. If you simply instantiate an Activity, it is a useless object and certainly does not have the context of your application with the OS.

Your interface implementation will need a reference to the actual Activity like this:

```
class AndroidPermissionChecker(private val activity: Activity) : PermissionManager {
    //...

    private fun makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            RECORD_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

And you pass it into the constructor like this:

```
initialize(aGame(AndroidPermissionChecker(this)), config)
```

Comment: the stars were a try to highlight the text. How should I code the PermissionManager 
 interface constructor since the Activity class is not available to the core module?

Comment: Just as I showed above. The AndroidPermissionChecker implementation of the PermissionManager is only in the Android module so it can freely refer to Activity. No changes are needed in your interface declaration in the core module.

Comment: Note that you will still need to call back to your game when permissions are granted. Your AndroidLauncher needs to implement ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, and in there when it receives a positive result, it must call some function on your game to tell it that permissions are now granted. So you need to make a `lateinit val game: YourGame` that stores a reference to your game that you pass to `initialize`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I've found out that libgdx screens aren't activities. This helped me also to understand the problem. "Different screens of the game are implemented within libgdx, not as separate activities." https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-and-configuration#android